# Qt module (QtSerialPort) not found in Qt custom build (cross compiled for ARM)

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I have Qt 5.5.1 custom build (cross compiled on x86 for ARM development). So the project is building on x86 host and then deployed to Jetson TK1 development board.

I have the error:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport

I can see build library: `/home/alan/work/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtserialport/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5.5.1`, source and header files for QtSerialPort module in qt build directory. So I think the module is build but not properly installed. Never deal with custom Qt modules so how to check if module build and installed correctly?

Update: Qt was build but was not installed into OS (Qt Creator allows to use such builds to creating kits).

Comment: the errormessage shows up when running qmake? and i assume you followed [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port#Building_and_Installing)?

Comment: yes, that's qmake error message.

Comment: I think there is no need to manually add/build QtSerialPort module to Qt 5.5.1. There is already `<qt source>/qtserialport` directory and build target in main Makefile of Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules only available after `install`. Another option - link module as separate library.